# Conditional ngClass based on current URL

Tags: angular

How do I implement `url1 ? class1 : class2` with Angular [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)?

**ADDED:**

Basically, I need to get the current URL and bind it to a conditional ngClass of an element so that if it is `url1`, then `class1` is applied to that element; otherwise `class2` is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Router to find out what is the current url...

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
    public url1: string = "";

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.url1 = this.router.url;
    }

}
```

Then, `[ngClass]="url1 ? 'style1' : 'style2'"` should work fine.

Don't forget to import the Router:
`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) states, `[ngClass]` expects several types of expressions:

> `<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>`

One of them string expression. It is

```
[ngClass]="url1 ? 'style1' : 'style2'"
```

This is not specific to ngClass but to Angular template syntax in whole.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I should have been more specific: I need to get the current url and pass it to [ngClass]

Comment: To pass it in which form? Please, update the question current output and the output you expect. What is the problem you're trying to solve? You likely have XY problem that should be addressed in another way. Most times urls shouldn't be accessed in Angular because router handles them.

Answer (score 0):

We can add a method to the component that returns different class names based on the URL:

```js
class MyComponent {
  getClasses() {
     const patterns = [
       {
         pattern: /a\.com/,
         className: 'serving-from-a',
       },
       {
         pattern: /b\.com/,
         className: 'serving-from-b',
       },
     ];

     return patterns
         .filter(p => p.pattern.test(window.location))
         .map(p => p.className)
         .join(' ');
  }
}
```

We can use this method in the template

```html
<div [ngClass]="getClasses()"></div>
```